# What is the best architecture for file management website?

Tags: asynchronous, file-upload, concurrency, architecture

Here is what I think my website should be able to provide to user.

1. Ability to upload file to the system. It should not blocking, user should be able to surf other pages of the website while upload is ongoing. Once upload is done user will get notified about upload.
2. User should be able to view of his/her uploaded files in website.
3. Ability to edit files in web browsers using third party APIs
4. Number of user are going to be around 5000, and all of them might upload files at the same time so performance should not decrease.
5. Where should I store this files? How to make sure that read and write of files on this directory should handle concurrent user request?

Considering above points. What should be the best way to architect this website?

Are there any existing web framework that play along with this type of architecture like rails, express?

Comment: Relative to file storage I can tip you NOT to use a DB. Hash the file content and use it as the storage file name. Persist original file name, hash value, storage path and user Id in any DB. Also you must read about file upload size limits

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the ability to browse the site while a file is uploading, you'll want to use something on the front end that overrides anchor tags and asynchronously fetches the next page - there might be a library or something to accomplish this but it should be easy to implement yourself with jQuery.

To make this easier (and for *many* other reasons), you'll almost definitely want to structure your site with an MVC (Model View Controller) architecture. Rails is structured this way, as is almost any web framework. It doesn't sound like what you're describing is better suited to Rails over PHP or Python etc so just use whatever language or framework you (or your developers) feel most comfortable with. You might want to do some research into available plugins for editing files (it really depends on *what type* of files you want to edit and *how*) and using those to influence your decision on which language to choose as well.

With regards to storing files on your server, any logical system should suffice. Perhaps:

```
/username/year/month/day/myFile.txt
```

You'll want to do something to ensure filenames don't clash as well. And obviously you'd want a database storing the information linking files to users.

Comment: By reading your first paragraph, I think it makes sense to build single page webapp?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. You might also want to consider users who have Javascript disabled though.